# Internal compiler error, while using boost spirit x3

Tags: c++, c++14, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I am currently implementing expressions and the operator hierarchy for my DSL, using boost spirit X3.

I think my parser is semanticaly correct, but when I try to compile it, while compiling, gcc and clang having HUGE memory footprint, compiles for an infinite amount of time, and then quits with "g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)".

I tried to minimize the code arround the expression parser, but its somehow not that trivial

[Here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8J3DNGd8xDy2v6Eo) is a demo.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here, or is this a bug?

EDIT:
 I think the problem is somwhere there:

```
auto const idx = as<ast::Operation>(helper::idxaccess_op > expression > ']');
auto const func = as<ast::Operation>(helper::func_call_op > expression%',' > ')');
auto const data = as<ast::Operation>(helper::access_op > expression);

auto const func_call_expr_def =
    primary_expr >> *(idx|func|data);
```

if I change `(idx|func|data)` to `(idx|func)`, it also compiles forever and uses up to 16GB of ram, but gcc is able to compile it, and the parser works how it should work.

EDIT II: Please have a look at the link above there is my example which causes the error.

Comment: Always include the code in your question, so that if the link goes down, the question is not broken.

Comment: An internal compiler error is kinda serious, so I think this is a bug in your compiler as it failed to find an error in your code and compile the code if it's correct.

Comment: @Rakete1111 how should I handle this, if the example which produces is way to big?

Comment: @Exagon Your link to the demo shows code that is not long, so I don't understand your question, you can add that code. Yes, you shouldn't add your whole application, but that's why you created a [mcve], right?

Comment: @Rakete1111 you saw that my mcve from the link consists of more than one file?

Comment: @Exagon Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't notice in my rush. Try to make it smaller?

Comment: @Rakete1111 allready tried, but this is the smallest I could achieve, I wasnt able to produce a smaler mcve

Answer (score 6):

I have done a bunch of changes on top of your source files. Please check those at http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sY2CQkXiMiLoS1BM

The changes are:

1. Changed the AST. It did not seem correct. Mainly the part adding 'Unary' to the variant.
2. Corrected the grammar. This is based on what I really could make of the grammar from your tests. I may be wrong, I have only tried making the first test case working. Better run a diff tool to compare my changes against yours, especially in 'parser.hpp'

NOTE: If my changes are not correct as per your requirements, the I would suggest you to enable debug 'BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG' and trace it. Can't stress enough how much BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG is useful in such cases.

parser.hpp

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include "ast.hpp"
#include "operators.hpp"
namespace parser{
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;


    template<typename T>
    auto as = [](auto p) { return x3::rule<struct _, T>{} = as_parser(p); };


    typedef x3::rule<struct multiplicative_expr_class, ast::Expression> multiplicative_expr_type;
    typedef x3::rule<struct expression_class, ast::Expression> expression_type;
    typedef x3::rule<struct primary_expr_class, ast::Operand> primary_expr_type;
    typedef x3::rule<struct func_call_call_class, ast::Expression> func_call_expr_type;
    typedef x3::rule<struct unary_expr_class, ast::Operand> unary_expr_type;



    const primary_expr_type primary_expr = "primary_expr";    
    const func_call_expr_type func_call_expr = "func_call_expr";
    const expression_type expression = "expression";
    const multiplicative_expr_type multiplicative_expr = "multiplicative_expr";
    const unary_expr_type unary_expr = "unary_expr";


    auto const primary_expr_def =
        +(x3::alpha | x3::char_('.'))
        | ( "(" > expression > ")" );

    auto const idx = as<ast::Operation>(helper::idxaccess_op > primary_expr > ']');
    auto const func = as<ast::Operation>(helper::func_call_op > primary_expr%',' > ')');
    auto const data = as<ast::Operation>(helper::access_op > expression);

    auto const func_call_expr_def =
        primary_expr >> *( idx | func | data );

    auto const unary_expr_def =
              func_call_expr
                      | as<ast::Operation>(helper::unary_op > func_call_expr);

    auto const multiplicative_expr_def =
        primary_expr >>  *(idx | func);

    auto const expression_def = multiplicative_expr_def;


BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(primary_expr,
                    func_call_expr,
                    multiplicative_expr,
                    unary_expr,
                    expression);

}
```

ast.hpp

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

#include <vector>

namespace ast{
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    enum class operator_t
    {
      _eq_,       // ==
      _ne_,       // !=
      _lt_,       // <
      _gt_,       // >
      _le_,       // <=
      _ge_,       // >=
      _add_,      // +
      _sub_,      // -
      _mul_,      // *
      _div_,      // /
      _mod_,      // %
      _pos_,      // unary +
      _neg_,      // unary -
      _not_,      // unary !
      _size_,     // unary #
      _bitnot_,   // unary ~
      _bitand_,   // &
      _bitor_,    // |
      _bitxor_,   // ^
      _shl_,      // <<
      _shr_,      // >>
      _and_,      // &&
      _or_,       // ||
      _idx_,      // []
      _apply_,    // ()
      _access_    // .
    };

    struct nil{};
    struct Expression;

    typedef x3::variant<
            nil,
            std::string,
            x3::forward_ast<Expression>
            //std::vector<Expression> //adding this as an operand for function parameter
    > Operand;

    struct Operation {
        operator_t operator_;
        Operand operand_;
    };

    struct Expression {
        Operand first_;
        std::vector<Operation> rest_;
    };
}
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::Operation, operator_, operand_)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::Expression, first_, rest_)
```

Comment: With my latest edit, following the earlier changes done in parser.hpp, I could make the second test case pass as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help, whats wrong with adding unary as an Operand? a unary expression is an Operand.
I have managed to get a parser which parses everything, with using a custom parser with a non template `parse()` method.
I will add this as an answer in the future, because its a totaly different approach.

Comment: TBH, I am a new user of spirit and also learning it :). The reason I removed it from the AST was because, it was same as 'struct Operation'. From there I went on with my understanding of how the grammar should work.

Comment: I just used a seperate struct, because this simplifies operations on the ast for me later.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has something to do with the template instantiation depth.
To avoid the `internal compiler error`, and to get acceptable compiletimes, for my parser I had to implement something like a template firewall, which is implemented as a custom parser, which calls a non templated function in the parse expression.

```
struct OptimizedExpressionParser : x3::parser<OptimizedExpressionParser> { 
    using attribute_type = ast::Expression;
    static bool const has_attribute = true;

    //parse fnction, which calls "non-templated"-firewall function
    template <typename Iter, typename Ctx, typename Attribute>
    bool parse(Iter& iFirst, const Iter& iLast, const Ctx& iCtx, x3::unused_type, Attribute& oAttr) const {
      ast::Expression a;
      return parse(iFirst, iLast, iCtx, x3::unused, a);
    }

    //parse fnction, which calls "non-templated"-firewall function
    template <typename Iter, typename Ctx>
    bool parse(Iter& iFirst, const Iter& iLast, const Ctx& iCtx, x3::unused_type, ast::Expression& oAttr) const {
      if (iFirst != iLast) {
        return parse_expression(iFirst, iLast, oAttr);
      }
      return false;
    }
   private:

   //"non-template"- parse function
   //of cause this is a template function, but the parser isnt a template argument
   template <typename Iter>
   bool parse_expression(Iter& iFirst, const Iter& iLast, ast::Expression& oAst) const {
      return x3::parse(iFirst, iLast, expression_impl, oAst);

  } 
  };
```

in this code `expression_impl` is the old "heavy" expression parser,
the new "firewalled" expression parser is this:

`auto const expression = OptimizedExpressionParser{};`

wherever I would like to use an expression in another parser, or for parsing I now use the `expression` object from my `OptimizedExpressionParser` parser.
this decrease ram usage, compiletimes and also the size of the resulting binary(which was about 1.6 Gb without the template firewall)
To see how this works out with my example [have a look here.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uz9Ff5EEw5Qa1WxJ)

To be honest, I would have never solved this problem on my own, the idea and most of the code comes from [here](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Horrible-compiletimes-and-memory-usage-while-compiling-a-parser-with-X3-td4689104.html#a4689217), I only changed it a bit to work out with my given example.